# How to fetch parameters of same array randomly using regular expression in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, post-processor

Like there are lots of values in  array
{"profile":"qa","job":"active","status":"green"}
{"profile":"dba","job":"non-active","status":"yellow"}
So there are multiple rows like this, I want to fetch profile and job of all the arrays randomly and it should be like that, if profile is selected as qa randomly say by regular expression post processor, then job value should also be "active" i.e

Same for dba profile, that if dba is fetched , then job value should be non active

Can this be achieved using regular expression for random fetch??i. giving match no as 0

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with JSON responses, hence would recommend you to use JSON extractor post processor as **$..['job','profile']** and set Match number to **0**. This way you can extract values from array in one go.

[image: JSON Post Processor]

You can use this variable name highlighted in subsequent requests like - **${entryJson}**

[image: Debug Sampler to visualize]

For Regular expression you can use **profile": "(.*?)"*** and **job": "(.?)"**
 in two of the expressions but using zero will return different values for each run.

Comment: After fetching all the values by putting match no to be 0, I need to extract job and profile values from response body and put in subsequent request as well. So the expression that u gave, will only list the available matches but how to put those values in subsequent request and it should be in a manner that job and profile values should be of particular row only out of 100 rows(as mentioned in earlier post). It's not like it fetching job of 1 row and profile of 5 row.